# При вводе данных в UITextField отправить запрос на сервер и обновить данные в UILabel без скрытия клавиатуры

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Доброго времени суток Коллеги!

Прошу подсказать как реализовать вводе данных в UITextField и отправку запроса на сервер а также полученные данные отобразить в UILabel и сделать это ТИХО (не отвлекая клиента от ввода, не скрывая ему клавиатуру).

Пользователь должен вводить сумму а в двух UILabel ниже должна автоматически пересчитываться комиссия (которую присылает сервер)

1) Сейчас одна из проблем заключается в том что: "пользователь вводит сумму, на сервер тихо отправляются запросы при вводе каждого нового(изменения) OnChange в UITextField, но при получении и отображении результата клавиатура скрывается"
Запрос на сервер отправляю с помощью:

```
DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now()) {
   let result = SendRequest()

   ... 
   Заполняю полученными значениями поля 2 филда
   ...

   self.tableView.ReloadData() //для того чтобы мои tableView обновил данные
}
```

2) "Направьте на путь истинный" как правильно обозвать механизм который я реализую ?! как гуглить подобное ?

P.s. За ссылку с реализацией подобного механизма отдельное спасибо.

Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При вызове `tableView.reloadData()` все ячейки в таблице грубо говоря пересоздаются. Естественно, что `UITextField` теряет фокус и клавиатура скрывается. 
Есть два варианта как в вашем случае этого избежать.

## Обновление одной ячейки

Если известен индекс ячейки с комиссией, то воспользуйтесь методом [reloadRows](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614935-reloadrows). В качестве анимации укажем [`.none`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/rowanimation/none) чтобы было незаметно для пользователя.

```swift
tableView.reloadRows(at indexPaths: [<индекс вашей ячейки>], with animation: .none)
```

## Обновление `UILabel`

В качестве второго варианта, при создании ячейки с комиссией, можно сохранить ссылку на `label` и при получении ответа от сервера, сразу обновлять значение в нём:

```swift
feeLabel.text = "новое значение комиссии"
```

Правда, если у вас изменится количество строк при выводе результата, в случае обновления только строки, высота ячейки не поменяется, поэтому пользуйтесь вторым вариантом только в том случае, если уверены, что текст всегда поместится в одну строку. Первый вариант в этом плане надежнее.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! В принципе так и поступил! 
Ранее все лэйблы находились в одной ячейке и независимо от того перерисовывал ли я все ячейки или перерисовывал одну ячейку клавиатура скрывалась в любом случае. Но пообщавшись с дизайнером разделили ввод суммы и вывод комиссий на 3 разных ячейки и сейчас перерисовываю только ячейки с комиссиями.